# Twitter Bootstrap horizontal form Inline Helptext Issue

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a form with Twitter Bootstrap and am having a tiny little problem aligning the "help-inline" element.

Here is the code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="purchase.php" method="post" >
    <fieldset>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="date">Details</label>
        <div class="controls controls-row">

            <input class="span2" type="text" id="date" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" title="Enter Date in DD/MM/YYYY Format Only" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" value="<?php echo $dateToday;?>" required>

            <input class="span2" type="text" name="resin" id="resin" title="Resin Name" placeholder="Resin Name" required/>

            <input class="span2" type="text" name="kg" id="kg" title="Enter Quantity in 00.0 format only" placeholder="Enter Quantity" pattern="\d+(\.\d{1})?" required/>

            <!-- Below is the problem in question-->
            <span class="help-inline">Error Text Here.</span>

        </div>
    </div>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Screenshot of the "Error Text Here" appearing misaligned: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/128104/Random/mia.png

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Though it's an old question and things have changed, I was working on that recently and as of today, `class="help-block"` or `class="help-inline"` placed inside an element on top of (i.e. before in DOM) the `<input>` or whatever the form element is does exactly what's required.

Answer (score 0):

I think the quickest fix is setting the `line-height` CSS property on the span in question. If you increase it, it should move a bit down and align better to the center of the textbox.

If you were to place all this in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), it would be easier for the users of StackOverflow to offer better solutions to you, because they'd be able to change code and see the behavior.

P.S. The date `input` field is missing the closing `/`.

Comment: Btw `<input>` doesn't have to have the closing `/` as long as this is supposed to be an HTML5 document which I guess it is as there are `data-` attributes within tags. No slash would also be valid HTML5 -  it's just a [syntactic sugar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3558200/588966)

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. That's something that I have left over in my best practices since xHTML.